# mac treeコマンド 色の変更の仕方

Tags: macos

Mac 10.12.6で treeコマンドを使用しています。
その際に-Cのオプションを使用して実行するとファイルの種類ごとに
色分けをしてくれるのですが、この色を変更したい場合には
Linuxでの設定は問題ないのですが、
macの場合にはどのファイルを編集すればよいのでしょうか？
manで書かれている下記のディレクトリにはファイルがないようです。

`/etc/DIR_COLORS          System color database.`

また自分で設定しているLSCOLORSとは別の色でtreeコマンドは出力されています。

Answer (score 2):

macOS自体にtreeコマンドは付いてこないようなので、HomebrewやMacPortsでインストールしたものだと思いますが、 `LSCOLORS` ではなく `LS_COLORS` (`_` がある)ではないでしょうか?

↓MacPortsのtree(1)↓

> Tree is a recursive directory listing program that produces  a  depth  indented
>   listing of files, which is colorized ala dircolors if the LS_COLORS environment
>   variable is set and output is to tty.

ここにも書かれていますが、端末に出力する場合はオプションなしで色付けされるようです。